# Vacuum tube emission (anode current, transconductance) percentage that is considered GOOD

Tags: datasheet, measurement, vacuum-tube

Russian vacuum tube datasheets almost always specifies anode current like Ia = 100 mA +/-20mA at some conditions. The same with  transconductance. But western tube datasheets specifies only one central value - for example Ia = 100 mA at some conditions. What is widely accepted tolerance in percentage to consider tube is good?

Comment: What do you mean by "good'???   There's such a huge variance in tube characteristics, even among the same tube in the same manufacturing lot, that you will "never" find a tube that runs exactly at 100mA.    That's gonna be a "nominal" value (i.e. typical, normal, usual, etc...)     Link to the datasheets and point out what you're seeing, can better explain it then....    The circuits are designed to accomodate these variances.... This can be done with negative feedback or with an adjustable bias supply (that you set when you replace the tubes).  Some amps even 'self bias' tubes.

Comment: For example - [B&K 707](https://tubesound.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/bk7071.jpg) tube tester - has "Repalce", "?", "Good" on its ampermeter. Like percentage - till about 70% tube considered good - that's about minus 25% of its nominal.

Comment: One thing about "Tube Testers" is that NONE of them have the same "range".   In other words, when you measure voltage with a voltmeter, and you read "10 volts", when you pickup another voltmeter and measure it again, you'll again get "10 volts".  Tube testers all use their own scales, and what is "good" is somewhat arbitrary.   It depends quite alot on what you're putting the tubes into... i.e. is it a power amp with 500V B+??   Or a preamp with only 200V on the plates?    Basically, it's a GUIDELINE, not an exact measure.

Comment: Basically, if you put the tube in your amp, and it sounds good to your ears, the tube is probably "good".   If it sounds weak, loses fidelity, etc... it's "bad".   But the point where a tube is no good depends so very much on the circuit it's in, and frankly, how sensitive your ears are.  (Assuming this is for an audio application...)

Comment: _...what is "good" is somewhat arbitrary..._ Yes, and that is the biggest question :) In case of russian tubes - while testing - I can easily discard them when some parameter is out of range. With western tubes - I have to think, usually I would use the value of maximum 30%. Tubes are tested for selling later - so it's unclear where they be used..

Comment: Tube testers are best used to compare one tube against another.   They don't even all measure the same characteristics! Can you link to the datasheets of the tubes in question?  I might also suggest move your question to a different forum.   There are lots of EE's here no doubt, but tubes kinda went the way of the dinosaur decades ago!   I'm into guitars, and thus tube amps.  You're the same, or you're an audiophile --  (Note my avatar  LOL )

Comment: Nobody else cares about tubes or bothers learning them.  I might recommend my own favorite forum: https://www.thegearpage.net/board/index.php?forums/amps-cabs-tech-corner-amplifier-cab-speakers.11/    I post there under the same name   ;)   Lots of very knowledgeable folks there who are more than happy to help.   Somebody might have a better idea of how to answer  your question than me.